# Splitting of natural number list

Tags: coq

I have a list of natural numbers and want to break it at each "new" element in the list. To make it clearer, if I have the list `[5; 5; 5; 10; 10; 15; 15]`, then I want to have as output the three lists: `[5; 5; 5]`, `[10; 10]` and `[15; 15]`. The main problem I have is that I don't know how to output several elements on a `Fixpoint`. I think I need to nest `Fixpoint`s but I just don't see how. As a very raw idea I have:

```
Fixpoint count (v:nat) (l:list nat) : nat :=
  match l with
  | [] => 0
  | h :: t => (if beq_nat h v then 1 else 0) + (count v t)
  end.
Fixpoint prefix (n: count)( l :list nat)=
 match l with
 | [] => []
 | m :: l' => if beq_nat count  m then []
           else m :: prefix n l'
 end.
```

Comment: What if the input is `[5; 5; 10; 10; 5; 5]`? Should it return `[[5; 5; 5; 5]; [10; 10]]` or `[[5; 5]; [10; 10]; [5; 5]]`?

Comment: [[5; 5; 5; 5]; [10; 10]]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to nest fixpoints in this example. This looks like, you would need an accumulator to remember the list that you already collected. What you want is a function that returns the following type: `list (list nat)`

From your `prefix` function, you can add a new parameter (initially set to the empty list `[]`) which remember the list of same numbers you already recognized:

```
Fixpoint prefix (acc: list (list nat)) (n: count)( l :list nat)=
  match l with
     | [] => acc
     | m :: l' => 
         (* Here some code that depending if m is equal to n will either 
            add a new list to acc or add a new element to the first list of acc *)

     end.
```

I did not try to be more precise in the answer as this looks like a homework assignment.

I would advise that you try to code this using a functional programming language (such as OCaml or Haskell) without using the imperative parts (allocation etc) and only then try to mimic this in Coq (if this is easier for you).

You may also want to look at some resources online on how to work with accumulators in functional programming.

Note also that your code for prefix does not compile.

Comment: First defined prefix ,suffix then combine them to make a list.
Fixpoint suffix n l :=
  match l with
  | [] => l
  | m :: l' => if beq_nat n m then l'
               else suffix n l'
  end.
Fixpoint split count l :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | m :: l' => prefix count (m :: l') :: split count (suffix count (m :: l'))
  end.

Comment: Definition add_acc m (s : list (list nat)) :=
  match s with
  | []      => [[m]]
  | s :: ss => (m :: s) :: ss
  end.
Fixpoint prefix (acc: list (list nat)) (n: nat)( l :list nat):=
  match l with
     | [] => acc
     | m :: l' => if beq_nat n m then
                 prefix n l' (add_acc m acc) 
               else
                 prefix acc (n+1) l'[]
            end.